# How to specify a cipher for an SSL connection in .NET?

Tags: .net, ssl, tcp

How can I specify a cipher suite to use in an SSL Connections?

I know that [Mentalis Seclib](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/seclib/download.qpx) got this feature however they don't maintain the project (and there are issues in that library with x64 OSes) as they say .NET Framework 2.0 introduced those features, however I couldn't find a way to do this in .NET Framework 3.5.

To be more specific I want to connect an HTTPS service by using NULL cipher, I would do the same thing with OpenSSL by using the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -cipher NULL
```

How can I do this in .NET?

*Also commercial or commercial friendly licensed library suggestions are welcome as well.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(My previous answer was ill-informed, I did not notice at first that the property I was referring to was read-only.)

In .NET 4, the `System.Net.Security.SslStream` class supports a new constructor, allowing you to provide an `EncryptionPolicy` value, which could be `NoEncryption`. This allows no encryption and request that a NULL cipher be used if the other endpoint can handle a NULL cipher.

Unfortunately this did not exist even in 3.5.

---

Not really part of the question, but I assume (and this is really for future readers) that you are of course aware of the relevant risks, of using SSL with a NULL cipher? And, the benefits you miss out on?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, you can set the ciphers when using [SChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380161%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) via the **palgSupportedAlgs**, **dwMinimumCipherStrength**, and **dwMaximumCipherStrength** parameters of the SCHANNEL_CRED struct.

In order to enable the NULL encryption algorithm, you should set **dwMinimumCipherStrength** to -1.

CAVEAT: This is based on the documentation only.  I am not a .NET developer, but I have been looking for an answer to the question because I support a service that has .NET clients.

Comment: Any idea how use SCHANNEL in .NET or any .NET wrapper for it?

Comment: For .NET 3.5, I do not.  .NET 4 introduced an EncryptionPolicy enum that allows you to configure HttpWebRequest to allow or require the use of NULL ciphers for HTTPS connections.  I sent that info to my .NET client, and he has confirmed that it works.  If that is useful to you, I can write up how to use it.

Comment: That sounds interesting would you care to point to me an article or throw me a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, you can use the SSLStream class. in .NET 4.0, as Matthieu says above, it allows you to specify the ciphers.